# How do i clear tmux screen while tailing logs?

Tags: tmux, iterm

I'm using tmux with iTerm2.

Clear screen using Ctrl-L works when i'm in bash, but does not work when i'm tailing server logs. How do i fix this?

Answer (score 18):

You can clear the current buffer using `send-keys -R` but keep in mind that the application running inside that buffer will not notice that the buffer contents have been wiped.

[Reference](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.terminal-emulators.tmux.user/2492)

Comment: i did this: `bind l send-keys -R; display "Cleared"`

Comment: This is the final clear screen that actually works for me like CMD-k in Terminal.app on Os X:
`bind -n C-k send-keys -R \; send-keys C-l \; clear-history`

Answer (score 5):

Ctrl-L is bound to a `readline` command. However, while you are running the command that tails your log, `bash` is not receiving keyboard input. You could suspend the tail with Ctrl-Z, clear the screen with Ctrl-L, and resume the tail with `fg`.

This is independent of `tmux`; I don't think `tmux` has anything like a `clear-pane` command, instead relying on the shell to handle that for you.

Comment: This one is the last thing/feature that I am too missing. Is it still not possible to this day?

Comment: See jjungnickel's answer.  It's a built in tmux command and it worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 5):

In OSX (Terminal and I believe iTerm2), CMD+K clears and removes scrollback but I'm not sure this works when tailing or in tmux.

A couple of links may have your answer:

- https://coderwall.com/p/rkstvg
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/31872/how-do-i-reset-the-scrollback-in-the-terminal-via-a-shell-command

Also, @chepner suggested suspending the command and this gave me the idea to add it as a key binding (note: I've tested this on Linux but I don't have OSX. The first link seems to indicate `clear-history` may work):

```
bind-key -n C-l send-keys C-z \; send-keys " reset && fg > /dev/null" \; send-keys "Enter"
```

Add this to your `~/.tmux.conf` then you can do `CTRL+l` and that will send the required keys and commands to the terminal to automate it.

`reset && fg` is prefixed with a space to exclude it from history.

The `> /dev/null` stops the original tail command being displayed but this might be useful so could be removed if you want to see it after clearing.

Comment: Cmd+k doesn't do it in tmux, but the binding does. Thanks!