# Is there a quicker way to clear scrollback buffer in tmux while tailing logs?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, tmux

According to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731760/how-do-i-clear-tmux-screen-while-tailing-logs), you could do the following keystroke sequence to clear the log:

1) ctrl-Z (to suspend)
2) cl (clear the screen)
3) fg (to resume)

Is there a way to do that without having to suspend? I tried ctrl-L while tailing but I get ^L  printed on the screen instead.

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it'll help you now but it may help others.

This blog post indicates how to do it on OSX.

https://coderwall.com/p/rkstvg

I can't verify this as I don't use OSX but this solution does not work on Linux (at least not for me).

I've added my own answer to the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731760/how-do-i-clear-tmux-screen-while-tailing-logs/24713366#24713366) you suggested which creates a key binding for the commands making it a little easier.